# Keep function references from changing when a new row is added to another worksheet?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, zapier

I am using Zapier to connect my Shopify store's new orders to an excel sheet for production.  When Zapier updates my first worksheet I need to have my second worksheet pull information from it.  The problem is that when Zapier updates a worksheet it actually adds a new row, meaning that all of my second worksheet's function references get shifted down a row and don't pull in the information.

```
=worksheet1!A2  =>  worksheet1!A3
=worksheet1!$A$2  => =worksheet1!$A$2
=VLOOKUP(C5,worksheet1!$A$2:B20,2,false)  =>  =VLOOKUP(C5,worksheet1!$A$3:B21,2,false)
```

I used VLOOKUP in a different structure and am only including that example to show that I have tried it.  Is there any way to keep my references static even when the testWorksheet has rows added to it?

Comment: Can you just use the whole column as a reference?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean.  As in `=worksheet1(Column(A1))`?

Comment: `worksheet1!$A:$B`.

Comment: That looks like it works! Thanks so much!  I'm not totally clear on WHY it works though.  I ended up using `=testWorksheet!$A:$A` anv `=testWorksheet!$B:$B` to pull the data in for each column.  Could you please explain?

Comment: If you reference the whole column, there are no row references to be updated... you're literally looking in the *entire column*.

Comment: Ahhh! Makes sense!  Thanks again!

Comment: Please consider posting this solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was selecting the entire Column as a Reference

```
 =testWorksheet!$A:$A
```